# Do catalogs fall under copyright laws?

Tags: copyright

I have a lot of catalogs featuring different products, and basically what I want to know is if there can be a problem to upload all those in a github repository so that anyone can download them, instead of going to the manufacturer sites one by one

Comment: Is your question if *creating* catalogs violates copyright or if catalogs can *be* copyrighted?

Comment: No. My question is if sharing with other people a catalog that is publicly available for free can be an infraction to some copyright law.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

Facts are not subject to copyright but a catalog is more than a list of facts are meets the criteria for a literary work under copyright law. The choice of how to present the facts (page composition, font choice, order of items, which photos to use etc.) is what makes a literary work - after all, a novel is just a collection of non-copyright words assembled in a particular order.

Comment: Certain simple catalogs in some countries might be considered uncopyrightable if the originality threshold is not met.

Comment: But they are free for anyone to download without registration - am I not allowed to share those with other people? For example, can't I give someone a grocery store flier I've found in my mailbox, and if I can, then can't I scan said flier and upload it to share with anyone on the internet?

Comment: @Jack yes, you can give someone your grocery flier just like you can give someone your Blue Ray of Avengers Endgame. What copyright law prevents you from doing is copying them - the hint is in the word “copy-right”.

Comment: "Copying" as of copying to share, or as of deriving content from. Look, I want to know if I can safely upload manuals and catalogs and not have them taken down

Comment: @Jack no, you can’t